# Resize the particular plot - Rmarkdown

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown

I have in one chunk a few plots and I want to resize them. I always change the size in the chunk options, like that:

````
```{r fig1, fig.height = 3, fig.width = 5}
```
````

But now I want to resize a particular one. I don't want to change the global options. Is there any option to resize particular chart? The reason is that I did a loop and in this loop is there a few charts. For example I want to resize this plot:

```
  print(ggplot(df_stat, aes(x = value,
                            y=nrow(df_stat))) +
          stat_halfeye()  +
          stat_slab(aes(fill = stat(level)), .width = seq(0.01, 1, by=0.01)) +
          labs(x = i,
               y = NULL) +
          geom_vline(xintercept = 4,
                     colour="red",
                     size=1)+
          theme_classic() +
          theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                axis.line.y = element_blank(),
                axis.line.x = element_blank(),
                legend.position="none"))
```

Comment: The answer, as you say is to put the options in the specific chunk in question.  As you have done in your example.  But you then refer to "global options", which is contradictory and confusing.  If your *current* chunk produces more than one figure, split the chunk up and adapt the options for only the chunk that produces the figure in question.

Comment: OK, so I must split my chunk with all plots to chunks with particular plot. But how can i link this chunks? Because i create a loop and the particular page is the particular variable. I need to add particular plot in function and then display in "general" chunk?

Comment: for(i in colnames(df_stat )) { 

  df_stat <- df_stat %>%
     melt(.,id.vars = c("ID")) %>%
     filter(.,variable == i)

Answer (score 2):

I think all the plots produced in a chunk will be displayed in the same size frame, but you could change the margins.  For example,

```
library(ggplot2)
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point() +
          theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1+i,1,1+i), "cm")))
}
```

[image: screenshot]

If you're using base graphics, use `par(mar = ...)` to
change the margins between plots.

Another way to do it is to save all the plots in a list, then display them in separate chunks, e.g.

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
result <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  result[[i]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()
}
```

```{r fig.height=2}
result[[1]]
```

```{r fig.height=3}
result[[2]]
```

```{r fig.height=4}
result[[3]]
```
````